# How to install Nokogiri on CentOS when "sudo gem install nokogiri" works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, centos, nokogiri

I am trying to set up a Rails project on CentOS (Amazon Linux) and the `bundle install` fails while installing Nokogiri with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb 
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

I verified I have the `libxslt` yum package.

`sudo gem install nokogiri` works fine, but I don't want to do `sudo gem install`. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: did you install the `libxslt-devel` package?

Comment: yes I just checked libxslt-devel.x86_64 1.1.28-3.8.amzn1            amzn-main

Comment: what does not make sense is it installed fine as sudo, so when I do a sudo gem list I see it installed.

Comment: how did you install ruby? `sudo gem` is most likely using the system ruby that's preinstalled with the distro

Comment: interesting, you are correct, I had a tarball of ruby 2.1, so I just did this: ruby -v #2.1 and sudo ruby -v #2.0

Comment: have you tried using `gem install nokogiri --with-xslt-lib=<location>`? The build flags are described in more detail in the CentOS section of the [Installing Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) page.